# Returning the result of a forkJoin from an ngrx/store effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am trying to return the result of a `forkJoin` in my effect using ngrx store, like this pseudocode demonstrates:

```
@Effect()
someEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.action$.pipe(
    ofType<SomeActionType>(ActionTypes.SomeActionType),
    switchMap((action: any) => 
        this.http.get<any>('some/url').pipe(
            map(someResult => {
                // this implementation is unimportant, just the gist of the flow I'm after
                const potentialResults = oneOrMany(someResult);

                if( potentialResults.length === 1 )   {
                    return new SomeAction(potentialResults[0]);
                } else {
                    observables: Observable<any> = getObservables(someResult);

                    forkJoin(observables).subscribe((result) =>
                        // this is where I get stuck    
                        return new SomeAction(result);
                    )
                }
            }
        ))
)
```

How can I synchronously return an action from the result of a `forkJoin` like this? At the moment, I'm dispatching an action directly to the store within the `forkJoin` block, but this is rather smelly and I would like to know how I can return this action within the `forkJoin` block, using another operator such as `map` or something along those lines. Any ideas?

Comment: `return forkJoin(...).map(result => new SomeAction(result))`

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately - I get an error indicating that the effect is not returning an action; presumably because the `return` is within the map, and not outside of the `forkJoin` block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't return an Observable from the map() callback. You need to use `switchMap()`(or another `xxxMap()`)  to do that. You also can't subscribe to the forkJoin observable. Instead, you must `map()`:

```
someEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.action$.pipe(
    ofType<SomeActionType>(ActionTypes.SomeActionType),
    switchMap(() => this.http.get<any>('some/url'),
    switchMap(someResult => {
        const potentialResults = oneOrMany(someResult);
        if (potentialResults.length === 1)   {
            return of(new SomeAction(potentialResults[0]));
        } else {
            const observables: Array<Observable<any>> = getObservables(someResult);
            return forkJoin(observables).map(result => new SomeAction(result))
        }
    })
)
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I needed. Thank you! Temporarily forgot how higher order observables worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Subject and return it:

```
someEffect$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(SomeType.Save),
mergeMap(action => {
  const obsList: Observable<any>[] = createList();

  const sub: Subject<Action> = new Subject<Action>();
  forkJoin(obsList).subscribe(() => {
    sub.next(new SomeAction());
    sub.complete();
  });
  return sub;
})));
```