# NGRX Loading Indicator with "nested" API Requests

Tags: api, asynchronous, redux, ngrx, effects

I am loading the reviews of a product from my API and store them in the state. One review looks something like this:

```
// Review
{
    _id: 'reviewId',
    productId: 'productId',
    creatorId: 'userId',
    writerId: 'userId',
    content: 'review content',
    rating: 4.5,
}
```

But I also need the information about the `product`, the `creator` and the `writer`. Therefore I have actions like `LoadManyByIds` (For users and products).

After everything is loaded the state might look like this:

```
// State
{
    reviewEntities: {
        reviewId1: {
            _id: 'reviewId1',
            productId: 'productId',
            creatorId: 'userId',
            writerId: 'userId',
            content: 'review content',
            rating: 4.5,
        },
        reviewId2: {},
        reviewId3: {},
        //...
    },
    userEntities: {
        userId1: {},
        userId2: {},
        //...
    },
    productEntities: {
        productId1: {},
        productId2: {},
        //...
    }
}
```

By connecting the different entities via ids, I am now able to select the necesary data.

**Issue**

I have to do *3 distinct API calls* to fetch all data and *want to display a loading spinner* in between. Because there are 3 different side effects I couldn't figure out how to update a `{ loading: boolean, loaded: boolean }` in the state

[image: Issue Visualized]

`loaded` should only be `true` if both, `users` and `products`, were loaded successfully.

Because I want to re-use `LoadUsers` and `LoadProducts` in other parts of the application I can't just set `loaded` of the reviews on `true` when those side effects finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you fire your requests within `@Effects`. If you have n requests, you might want to fire them using some of the combining operators like: `forkJoin`, `combineLatest` or `zip`.

`forkJoin` is probably a good start:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Once you get all responses, you could raise `xCompleteAction` that sets `loading: false`.

PS.
Good mental model is that loader status is not related to actual api calls but to effects which, in turn, can react to single action by sending single or multiple api calls.

Comment: okay, sounds great! Could you attach an example of how this effect would work, because I can't seem to get this working. ([what I have right now](http://prntscr.com/kg7pbp))

Comment: you should find examples you look for here: https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293 there are several solutions/approaches

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! Do you know how to dispatch actions from inside a `forkJoin`?

Comment: `forkJoin(observablesCollection).map(result => new Action(result))`. example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779521/returning-the-result-of-a-forkjoin-from-an-ngrx-store-effect

Comment: `.map` does not exist. I also tried to use `.pipe(map(result => ...))` but then, the result is undefined

Comment: Is it possible to make the API call inside the forkJoin via another Effect (without directly using a service)?

Answer (score 0):

You could think loading state as number of requests currently incomplete.

So before dispatching a request you could dispatch ONGOING_REQUESTS_INCREMENT with payload 1 and when a request completes / errors you could dispatch ONGOING_REQUESTS_DECREMENT. You might even add some "scope" to that if needed.

The way I handled similar feature was via Angular interceptor dispatching increment/decrement events. I was completely satisfied with the global loading state.